# Tarantool Error - Procedure 'vshard.storage.buckets_count' is not defined

Tags: tarantool

I'm trying to initialize a router and I get this error.

```
 Procedure 'vshard.storage.buckets_count' is not defined
```

All respose:
[response screen shote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgKZ.png)

I also do not have buckets. What could be the problem?

Comment: Whether `vshard` global variable is assigned on all storages (`_G.vshard = require('vshard')`)?

Comment: Just met this situation myself. Added the recommendation above as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to set the `vshard` global variable:

```
_G.vshard = require('vshard')
```

Comment: -- having global variable (required by vshard.rebalancer, vshard.discovery).
It is enough to call
`vshard = require('vshard')`